# With JPA how to treat input and output fields differently?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I have an entity class that my REST API returns. And the class contains fields such as createDate or id that I want clients to be aware of when they make GET calls.

At the same time, I don't want clients to include these fields in POST requests. My question is how do you treat such fields? Do you just annotate them as @Null?

And how do I indicate in Swagger that id and createDate should not be populated in POST requests? @JsonIgnore doesn't quite do the trick as it would remove them altogether from swagger. What is the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

Eaiser you can using `DTO` as the request/response in your case, for exampke, you have an `Entity` whichi has `ID`, `Name`, `CreatedAt` and `UpdatedAt` fields, then your can create the rorresponding EntityResponse with all those fields and the corresponding EntityRequest which only have the `Name` field. and using some mapping tools like BeanUtils/MapStruct to tansfer the data between the `Entity` and the `DTO` consistently.

Comment: Thanks @Liping. I am trying to avoid a DTO explosion.

Answer (score 0):

JsonView is the answer to my question: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation